Android 12: Remove animated icon from splash screen
I'm using new splash screen API, I want to have image as background and get rid of icon that appears in the middle of splash screen.
I achieved that by setting the icon to empty drawable, but it seems like a stupid idea. Is there a better, proper way to do it?
splash.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/img_splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/empty</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyApp</item>
    </style>
</resources>

empty.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>


Just design a custom fragment as splash screen and load that fragment first and then using a handler move to the next screen

Yeah, but then I would have two splash screens – the default one from the system, and when the app is ready to launch, there would be a fake splash screen as a custom fragment. I think this behavior creates a bad user experience because it keeps the user on the splash screen even when the app is ready to use. That's why I wanted to modify the system splash screen instead of creating a fake one.
